# Support Vector Classifiers for Overlapping Classes

Tags: machine-learning, svm, lagrange-multipliers

I am currently studying support vector classifiers (SVC), more specifically, the solution to the Lagrangian (Wolfe) dual function with the help of the book "*The Elements of Statistical Learning*" by Trevor Hastie, Robert Tibshirani, and Jerome Friedman. It is said that from the Karush-Kuhn-Tucker (KKT) conditions, we can infer that for a support vector $x_i$ that lies on the edge of the margin, the corresponding Lagrange multiplier $\alpha_i$ lies in $0 < \alpha_i < C$ with $C$ being the cost parameter in the Lagrange primal function.

Given the KKT conditions

[image: KKT conditions 1]

[image: KKT condition 2]

how can we infer that $\alpha_i \neq C$ for a support vector $x_i$ on the margin edge?

Thank you in advance.